# FlatFileItemReader tab delimiter not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I checkout this project from spring:
https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-batch-processing

Source: https://spring.io/guides/gs/batch-processing/

I replace the ',' with 'tab' in 'sample-data.csv:

```
Jill    Doe
Joe Doe
Justin  Doe
Jane    Doe
John    Doe
```

Then I add the new Delimiter to the reader:

```
@Bean
public FlatFileItemReader<Person> reader() {
    return new FlatFileItemReaderBuilder<Person>()
        .name("personItemReader")
        .resource(new ClassPathResource("sample-data.csv"))
        .delimited()
        .delimiter(DelimitedLineTokenizer.DELIMITER_TAB) // NEW DELIMITER
        .names(new String[]{"firstName", "lastName"})
        .fieldSetMapper(new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<Person>() {{
            setTargetType(Person.class);
        }})
        .build();
}
```

When I launch I get this error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.IncorrectTokenCountException: Incorrect number of tokens found in record: expected 2 actual 1
    at org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.AbstractLineTokenizer.tokenize(AbstractLineTokenizer.java:142) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper.mapLine(DefaultLineMapper.java:43) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader.doRead(FlatFileItemReader.java:180) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    ... 50 common frames omitted
```

I have tried with  '@' delimiter -> it works.
For some reason, I can't make it work with the tab delimiter...

Of course in my real project, I have an input file with 'tab' separators...

Any solution here?

Comment: Your 2nd line looks strange: `Joe Doe` maybe the tokenizer complains about that?

Comment: There is an open ticket for this issue: https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH-2738. It will be fixed in next release

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cant't set the tab delimiter that way. Since tab ('\t') doesnt contain any actual text it is ignored by the `DelimitedLineTokenizer` in static `DelimitedBuilder` class in `FlatFileItemReaderBuilder.java` . Any non-whitespace delimiter can be set using above code that you have given in the question.

[FlatFileItemReaderBuilder sourceCode](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-infrastructure/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/item/file/builder/FlatFileItemReaderBuilder.java)

This is how the `LineTokenizer` instance is built in `FlatFileItemReaderBuilder.java`.

```
public DelimitedLineTokenizer build() {
        Assert.notNull(this.fieldSetFactory, "A FieldSetFactory is required.");
        Assert.notEmpty(this.names, "A list of field names is required");

        DelimitedLineTokenizer tokenizer = new DelimitedLineTokenizer();

        tokenizer.setNames(this.names.toArray(new String[this.names.size()]));

        // the hasText ignores the tab delimiter.

        if(StringUtils.hasText(this.delimiter)) {
            tokenizer.setDelimiter(this.delimiter);
        }
// more code
```

So to fix this issue, you need to provide bean of Type DelimitedLineTokenizer explicitly configured with tab delimiter.

use below code in your spring configuration file to set the tab delimiter:

```
@Bean
public FlatFileItemReader<Person> reader() {
    return new FlatFileItemReaderBuilder<Person>().name("personItemReader")
            .resource(new ClassPathResource("sample-data.csv"))
            .lineMapper(lineMapper()).build();
}

@Bean
public DefaultLineMapper<Person> lineMapper(){
      DefaultLineMapper<Person> lineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper<>();
      lineMapper.setLineTokenizer(lineTokenizer());
      lineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<Person>() {
                {
                    setTargetType(Person.class);
                }
            });
      return lineMapper;
}

@Bean
public DelimitedLineTokenizer lineTokenizer() {
    DelimitedLineTokenizer tokenizer = new DelimitedLineTokenizer(DelimitedLineTokenizer.DELIMITER_TAB);
    tokenizer.setNames(new String[] { "firstName", "lastName" });
    return tokenizer;
}
```

Comment: Perfect: I understand where I was wrong & it works perfectly. Thank you

Comment: @Tyvain glad to hear that it helped.

Answer (score 5):

Simple way:

```
@Bean
public FlatFileItemReader<Person> reader() {
    return new FlatFileItemReaderBuilder<Person>()
            .name("personItemReader")
            .resource(new ClassPathResource("sample-data.csv"))
            .lineTokenizer(new DelimitedLineTokenizer(DelimitedLineTokenizer.DELIMITER_TAB) {{
                setNames(new String[]{"firstName", "lastName"});
            }})
            .fieldSetMapper(new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<Person>() {{
                setTargetType(Person.class);
            }})
            .build();
}
```